# Conflicting types when calling a method

Tags: c, implicit-declaration

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 9

void main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

  printBoard();

}

void printBoard(void) {
  int row,col;
  row=col=0;

  for(row;row<MAX;row++)   //row navigation
    for(col;col<MAX;col++){//column navigation
      printf("r:%d,c:%d",row,col);
    }/*End Column Nav*/

  printf("\n");
}
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here - the error I get :

"warning: conflicting types for ‘printBoard’ [enabled by default]
note: previous implicit declaration of ‘printBoard’ was here"

Comment: At the time of calling, here is no prototype in scope for PrintBoard() Also: main() returns int (there is a(n invisible)  prototype in scope)

Comment: Definite duplicate of [Getting "conflicting types for function" in C, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549631/getting-conflicting-types-for-function-in-c-why)

Comment: The unanswered question is: why does you compiler accept `void main()` ? It is terribly wrong for the same reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a [function prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) for `printBoard` above `main()` e.g.,

```
void printBoard(void);

void main(...)
```

Comment: Will accept as answer in 6min. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared function after calling it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 9

void printBoard(void) {
  int row,col;
  row=col=0;

  for(row;row<MAX;row++)   //row navigation
    for(col;col<MAX;col++){//column navigation
      printf("r:%d,c:%d",row,col);
    }/*End Column Nav*/

  printf("\n");
}
void main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

  printBoard();

}
```

This should work pretty fine.

Edit: You should declar all function before calling any of them.
Like  void printBoard(void);

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the method before it is declared.

Solve the problem by:

1) Moving the definition of `void printBoard(void)` above main or

2) adding a declaration above `main`. Just this line: `void printBoard(void);`