# Can't return static array

Tags: c

Probably a very simple question but I couldn't figure out the reason. All the given code is in the same file.

This is the definition of one of the arrays. It is defined outside of every method.

```
unsigned char KEY_40_COMPARE_VALUES[] = {
85,102
,119,134
,147,158
,165,169
,169,165
,158,147
,134,119
,102,85
,67,50
,35,22
,11,4
,0,0
,4,11
,22,35
,50,67
};
```

This is the code:

```
unsigned char * getCompareValuesForIndex(char index)
{
    if (index == 0)
    {
        return KEY_28_COMPARE_VALUES;
    }

    if (index == 1)
    {
        return KEY_30_COMPARE_VALUES;
    }

    if (index == 2)
    {
        return KEY_32_COMPARE_VALUES;
    }

    if (index == 3)
    {
        return KEY_33_COMPARE_VALUES;
    }

    if (index == 4)
    {
        return KEY_35_COMPARE_VALUES;
    }

    if (index == 5)
    {
        return KEY_37_COMPARE_VALUES;
    }

    if (index == 6)
    {
        return KEY_39_COMPARE_VALUES;
    }

    else
    {
        return KEY_40_COMPARE_VALUES;
    }
}
```

This is the compilation error I get:

```
conflicting types for 'getCompareValuesForIndex'
```

Comment: Where are you calling this function `getCompareValuesForIndex` ?

Comment: You can also replace all those if statements with a lookup table.

Comment: Can you present the definition of the function? also search the project for the word `getCompareValuesForIndex` check if you have another definition/other use of this name

Comment: Possibly this is the issue?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549631/getting-conflicting-types-for-function-in-c-why

Comment: can you share a short version of complete code ? @QuestionC might be right here ....

Comment: Ok thanks, it was a declaration issue. Someone may close the question if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An error like this usually happens when you make a call of your function before providing a prototype for it, and ahead of its declaration in the file. In this case the compiler assumes that

- Any arguments the function takes are of type `int`, and
- The value the function returns is of type `int`

Essentially, the function looks like this to the compiler:

```
int getCompareValuesForIndex(int index) { // <<= What compiler thinks
    ...
}
```

When compiler sees the actual declaration, it issues an error.

To fix this problem, either (1) provide a function prototype ahead of the call, or (2) move the definition to be ahead of the first use of your function.

**Note:** With this issue out of the way, consider optimizing your function, by adding a static array, like this:

```
unsigned char *KEY_COMPARE_VALUES[] = {
    KEY_28_COMPARE_VALUES
,   KEY_30_COMPARE_VALUES
,   KEY_32_COMPARE_VALUES
,   KEY_33_COMPARE_VALUES
,   KEY_35_COMPARE_VALUES
,   KEY_37_COMPARE_VALUES
,   KEY_39_COMPARE_VALUES
};
```

Now your function can be rewritten like this:

```
unsigned char * getCompareValuesForIndex(char index) {
    return (index >=0 && index < 7) ? KEY_COMPARE_VALUES[index] : KEY_40_COMPARE_VALUES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will accept the answer after the time limit.