# Error: Conflicting types for function in c

Tags: c

I am trying to make a four  band resistance calculator in c. To find tolerance I've the float type function with  a single character type  one dimensional array
as parameter named 'tolerance'. All the functions are working properly but not  this one. The error I got is "Conflicting types for tolerance'. Kindly guide me whats wrong in it. Code is given below.

```
void main()
{
     unsigned int e,f,g;
     char a[10],b[10],c[10],d[10];
     printf("enter the band color ");
     scanf("%s %s %s %s",a,b,c,d);
     if(strcmp(a,"red")==0 || strcmp(a,"RED")==0)
     {
          e = 20;
     }
     else if(strcmp(a,"black")==0 || strcmp(a,"BLACK")==0)
     {
          e = 0;

     }
     else if(strcmp(a,"brown")==0 || strcmp(a,"BROWN")==0)
     {
          e = 10;
     }
     else if(strcmp(a,"orange")==0 || strcmp(a,"ORANGE")==0)
     {
          e = 30;
     }
     else if(strcmp(a,"yellow")==0 || strcmp(a,"YELLOW")==0)
     {
          e = 40;
     }
     else if(strcmp(a,"green")==0 || strcmp(a,"GREEN")==0)
     {
          e = 50;
     }
     else if(strcmp(a,"blue")==0 || strcmp(a,"BLUE")==0)
     {
          e = 60;
     }
     else if(strcmp(a,"violet")==0 || strcmp(a,"VIOLET")==0)
     {
          e = 70;
     }
     else if(strcmp(a,"grey")==0 || strcmp(a,"GREY")==0)
     {
          e = 80;
     }
     else if(strcmp(a,"white")==0 || strcmp(a,"WHITE")==0)
     {
          e = 90;
     }
     f = e+second(b);
     g = f*multiplier(c);
     printf("resristance: %u ohm \n",g);
     printf("tolerance: %lf",tolerance(d));
     getche();
}

int second(char u[])
{
     if(strcmp(u,"black")==0 || strcmp(u,"BLACK")==0)
     {
          return 0;
     }
     else if(strcmp(u,"brown")==0 || strcmp(u,"BROWN")==0)
     {
          return 1;
     }
     else if(strcmp(u,"red")==0 || strcmp(u,"RED")==0)
     {
          return 2;
     }
     else if(strcmp(u,"orange")==0 || strcmp(u,"ORANGE")==0)
     {
          return 3;
     }
     else if(strcmp(u,"yellow")==0 || strcmp(u,"YELLOW")==0)
     {
          return 4;
     }
     else if(strcmp(u,"green")==0 || strcmp(u,"GREEN")==0)
     {
          return 5;
     }
     else if(strcmp(u,"blue")==0 || strcmp(u,"BLUE")==0)
     {
          return 6;
     }
     else if(strcmp(u,"violet")==0 || strcmp(u,"VIOLET")==0)
     {
          return 7;
     }
     else if(strcmp(u,"grey")==0 || strcmp(u,"GREY")==0)
     {
          return 8;
     }
     else if(strcmp(u,"white")==0 || strcmp(u,"WHITE")==0)
     {
          return 9;
     }
}

int multiplier(char color[10])
{
     if(strcmp(color,"black")==0 || strcmp(color,"BLACK")==0)
     {
          return 1;
     }
     else if(strcmp(color,"brown")==0 || strcmp(color,"BROWN")==0)
     {
          return 10;
     }
     else if(strcmp(color,"red")==0 || strcmp(color,"RED")==0)
     {
          return 100;
     }
     else if(strcmp(color,"orange")==0 || strcmp(color,"ORANGE")==0)
     {
          return 1000;
     }
     else if(strcmp(color,"yellow")==0 || strcmp(color,"YELLOW")==0)
     {
          return 10000;
     }
     else if(strcmp(color,"green")==0 || strcmp(color,"GREEN")==0)
     {
          return 100000;
     }
     else if(strcmp(color,"blue")==0 || strcmp(color,"BLUE")==0)
     {
          return 1000000;
     }
     else if(strcmp(color,"violet")==0 || strcmp(color,"VIOLET")==0)
     {
          return 10000000;
     }
     else if(strcmp(color,"grey")==0 || strcmp(color,"GREY")==0)
     {
          return 100000000;
     }
     else if(strcmp(color,"white")==0 || strcmp(color,"WHITE")==0)
     {
          return 1000000000;
     }

}

float tolerance(char color[10])
{
     if(strcmp(color,"brown")==0 || strcmp(color,"BROWN")==0)
     {
          return 1;
     }
     else if(strcmp(color,"red")==0 || strcmp(color,"RED")==0)
     {
          return 2;
     }
     else if(strcmp(color,"green")==0 || strcmp(color,"GREEN")==0)
     {
          return 0.5;
     }
     else if(strcmp(color,"blue")==0 || strcmp(color,"BLUE")==0)
     {
          return 0.25;
     }
     else if(strcmp(color,"violet")==0 || strcmp(color,"VIOLET")==0)
     {
          return 0.1;
     }
     else if(strcmp(color,"grey")==0 || strcmp(color,"GREY")==0)
     {
          return 0.05;
     }
     else if(strcmp(color,"gold")==0 || strcmp(color,"GOLD")==0)
     {
          return 5;
     }
     else if(strcmp(color,"silver")==0 || strcmp(color,"SILVER")==0)
     {
          return 10;
     }
}
```

Comment: You need functions prototypes. `main` doesn't know what `tolerance` is. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549631/getting-conflicting-types-for-function-in-c-why

Comment: You also miss an else branch in every function